# Firebase storage save files privately for app use only

Tags: android, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I uploaded a bunch of images on Firebase storage and I want to download them and store them locally when the user first launches the app.

the downloaded files

1. Must be saved locally so they are available even offline
2. My app only should be able to access to the files, the user does not have to be able to get the images as pngs from a file manager.
3. must be download all at once. I have a folder called "images". I need to download all the images within that folder. Downloading one by one it's kind of a problem since I got 1200 images.

I looked at this code from the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_in_memory)

```
islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg");

File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

but as far as I understand it does not allow me to download the whole folder content at once (point 3) and the data will be saved as jpegs so will be accessible via file manager (point 2). Are this assumptions right? What would be a viable alternative solution?

Comment: You have the know the specific name of a file to download it.  There is no such operation as "download everything in a folder".  In fact, there are not actually folders in Cloud Storage from the client's point of view.  There are just a collection of files that have a representation that looks like a path.

Comment: mmm that's kind of a problem to me. I got 1200 images + 300 mp3 to download. having a line of code for everyone of them seams crazy... Isn't there any other way?